# Create random points based in distance and boundary conditions

Tags: r, random, r-sf, r-sp

In my example, I have:

```
# Packages
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Create some points
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  gr = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)),
  x  = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10)
)
df <- st_as_sf(df,coords = c("x","y"),remove = F, crs = 4326)
df.laea = st_transform(
  df,
  crs = "+proj=laea +x_0=4600000 +y_0=4600000 +lon_0=0.13 +lat_0=0.24 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
)
# Create a countour of the area
ch <- st_convex_hull(st_union(df.laea))

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = ch, fill = "white", color = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = df.laea,color = "black")
```

[image: areaExample]

Now, I'd like to create 10 random points but the conditions are that this points must be inside the `ch` boundaries and a minimum distance of 10 meters of each `df.laea` points that exist inside this `ch` area.

Please, any help with it?

Comment: How should the the points be distributed across the restricted space? Uniformly?

Comment: Random distribuition, please

Comment: There are many different random distributions. But I guess you mean uniform distribution by that

Comment: `st_sample(type = "random"` are OK to me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only tricky thing here is that a simple `st_difference()` of your polygon and the buffered points will return ten polygons, each with one of the points removed. Thus you have to either use a `for` loop or `reduce()` to remove one buffered point after the other from the polygon. To use `reduce()` you have to transform the vector to a proper list of `sf` instead of an `sfc` vector. This is what I did below.

```r
# Packages
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

ch_minus <- df.laea$geometry |> 
  st_buffer(10000) |> 
  {\(vec) map(seq_along(vec), \(x) vec[x])}() |> # Transform buffered points to reducible list
  reduce(.init = ch, st_difference) 

sampled_points <- st_sample(ch_minus, 10)

ch_minus |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_sf(data = sampled_points)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can buffer the points by the distance you'd like, then intersect those polygons with the `ch` polygon. From there, use `st_sample` and the associated arguments to get the points you want.

Example code:

```r
## buffer df.laea 10m
laea_buff <- st_buffer(df.laea, dist = 10000) #changed dist to 10km to make it noticable in plot

# area to sample from:
sample_area <- st_intersection(ch, laea_buff)

# sample above area, all within 10km of a point and inside the `ch` polygon
points <- st_sample(sample_area, size = 10)

#plotting:
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = points, color = 'red') + 
  geom_sf(data = laea_buff, color = 'black', fill = NA) + 
  geom_sf(data = ch, color = 'black', fill = NA) + 
  geom_sf(data = sample_area, color = 'pink', fill = NA) + 
  geom_sf(data = df.laea, color = 'black', size = .5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Very nice, but I think OP wanted to exclude the 10m around the points, not the other way around

Comment: Yeh, @mrhellmann is the `sample_area` the `st_difference` and not `st_intersection`.

Comment: @Leprechault Looks like I misread the question. st_difference is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As a comment on the nice answer by [shs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11932936/shs): it is possible to first use a `sf::st_combine()` call on the df.laea object & merge the 10 points to a single multipoint geometry.

This, when buffered, will work as an input for the necessary `sf::st_difference()` call to form a sampling area with holes, removing the need for a for cycle / map & reduce call.

```
# Packages
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)


# Create some points
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  gr = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)),
  x  = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10)
)
df <- st_as_sf(df,coords = c("x","y"),remove = F, crs = 4326)

df.laea = st_transform(
  df,
  crs = "+proj=laea +x_0=4600000 +y_0=4600000 +lon_0=0.13 +lat_0=0.24 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
) 

# merge 10 points to 1 multipoing
mod_laea <- df.laea %>% 
  st_combine()


# sampling area = difference between hull and buffered points
sampling_area <- mod_laea %>% 
  st_convex_hull() %>% 
  st_difference(st_buffer(mod_laea, 10000))

# sample over sampling area 
sampled_points <- st_sample(sampling_area, 10)


# a visual overview
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = sampling_area, fill = "white", color = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = df.laea, color = "black")  +
  geom_sf(data = sampled_points, color = "red", pch = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I knew there must be a way to do that with an `sf` function, but could not find it. My solution was a bit of a hack, but it got the job done. This should be the accepted solution.